# Passing method as parameter to function

Tags: c#, sorting, delegates, func

Is there a way of passing in a method to a function as a parameter and then calling it via list.Sort()? I've tried this:

```
public static string BuildHumanSitemap(Func<TreeNode, TreeNode, int> sortMethod, params string[] classNames)
{
    //calling list sort on method passed as parameter
    nodes.sort(sortMethod);
 }
```

Where the functions i want to pass in all take the same params e.g.

```
private static int SortByDateCreated(TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
{
    DateTime xT = (DateTime)x["DocumentCreatedWhen"];
    DateTime yT = (DateTime)y["DocumentCreatedWhen"];
    return xT.CompareTo(yT);
}
```

I've also tried using an `Action` delegate type but the sort method complains when i pass it as a parameter. Can anyone offer a suggestion on how to do this?

Thankyou

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Also, you said the sort method complains when you use Action, can you please post what the error message is?

Comment: What's the type of `nodes`? And more specifically what's the signature for the `sort` method?

Comment: If you're talking about `List<T>.Sort`, that method does not provide an overload that takes a delegate.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen `nodes` is a `List<TreeNode>`. `Sort` is just a `List<T>.Sort()`. @Andrew so i guess what i want to achieve is not possible?

Comment: @DGibbs: Not via any built-in library functions that I know of, you could write an extension method to do it though.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - thanks. It works when i call `nodes.Sort(SortByDateCreated);` rather than passing in a parameter which is why i thought it might be possible out of the box somehow

Comment: @DGibbs: Looks like I could be wrong--check out lazyberezovsky's answer below...

Comment: Yep, he has the solution. Thanks guys

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Just for completeness, here's [the documentation for the `List<T>.Sort` overload which takes in a delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create new Comparison delegate and pass it to Sort method:

```
nodes.Sort(new Comparison<TreeNode>(sortMethod));
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe instead of taking in a `Func<,,>` delegate, you should consume a `Comparison<>` delegate. Because that's what `List<>` wants (for historical reasons; the `List<>.Sort` method was written for .NET 2.0, before the `Func` delegates were introduced).

Therefore:

```
public static string BuildHumanSitemap(Comparison<TreeNode> sortMethod, params string[] classNames)
{
  //calling list sort on method passed as parameter
  nodes.Sort(sortMethod);
}
```

Then call your method very simply like this:

```
BuildHumanSitemap(SortByDateCreated);
```

where `SortByDateCreated` is the "method group" from your question.

There's no need for first creating a delegate instance of type `Func<TreeNode, TreeNode, int>` and then create another delegate instance (of type `Comparison<TreeNode>`) which references the first one.

Of course you can also call your `BuildHumanSitemap` method with a lambda arrow as the first argument.

Comment: I like this way better, have a +1

Comment: @DGibbs Thanks. You can even change your "accept" mark `✔` to honor this answer (but only if you feel it's better than the answer you previously accepted).

Answer (score 0):

It works this way:

```
  TreeView.TreeViewNodeSorter = new CustomNodeSorter();

  private class CustomNodeSorter : IComparer
  {
     public int Compare(object x, object y)
     {
         DateTime xT = (DateTime)x["DocumentCreatedWhen"];
         DateTime yT = (DateTime)y["DocumentCreatedWhen"];
         return xT.CompareTo(yT);
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with `IComparer<T>`.

**Comparer**

```
public class MyTreeNodeComparer : IComparer<TreeNode>
{
     public int Compare(TreeNode x, TreeNode y)
     {
         DateTime xT = (DateTime)x["DocumentCreatedWhen"];
         DateTime yT = (DateTime)y["DocumentCreatedWhen"];
         return xT.CompareTo(yT);
     }
}
```

**Usage**

```
list.Sort(new MyTreeNodeComparer());
```